# Use local packages while deploying with Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am wanting to deploy my application however, I want to be able to use a local package (located in my package.json) in my project. When I'm buliding my application, it is unable to find the package. Is there anyway I can fix this?

[image]

Docker File

```
FROM node:12

WORKDIR /var/v5/com.app.api

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

ADD . /var/v5/com.app.api
RUN npm run build

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3011

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Docker Compose

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  app:
    container_name: com.app.api
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - '3011:3011'
    network_mode: 'host'
```

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks.

Comment: It is probably your path being incorrect. Where is your package exactly?

Comment: @uglyCoder It works fine when I don't deploy with Docker... It's definitely in the correct location.

Comment: That happens because the package is looked for in the path set in your ENV. I am talking about actual path of the  package you are trying to copy from.

Comment: The path to the package I need is /var/v5/core

Comment: Exactly my point, the place you are looking for the package at is incorrect.

Comment: Soo I'm guessing I need to `ADD . /var/v5/core`?

Comment: Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Accept my answer at least, lol!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because dockerfile is not able to find your package to copy. Give the complete path of the package you are looking for in COPY instruction.

Something like:

```
COPY /path/to/mypackage/package.json ./
```